# Storing an Array of Entities to Person.etx in PolicyCenter 9

Tags: guidewire, gosu

I am working in Guidewire PolicyCenter V9, I have an array of policies that I am trying to store in the Person entity via an extension of the original entity.

I have attempted to create an array on the Person.etx but cannot establish how to store the array of policies and link it to this entity.

Answer (score 7):

It's most likely ill-advised to create such an array as it will denormalize the relationship between Contact and PolicyPeriod, which already exists.  This will not only represent duplicative data in the database, it will have the problem of requiring maintenance, and possibly getting out of synch with the existing relationship present in the database.

A virtual property is likely a better solution to this problem, as it doesn't possibly introduce database inconsistencies and doesn't denormalize the database further.

I'm assuming the requirement to return PolicyPeriods rather than Policies as these are the typical unit-of-work for Policy transactions, and the entity which contains Policy Number, but if this isn't what you're after, you'd just replace elt.Branch with elt.Branch.Policy, and change the return type and name of the virtual property.

```
package com.acme.enhancements

uses gw.api.database.Query
uses gw.api.database.Relop

enhancement PersonEnhancement : entity.Person {
 
  property get PolicyPeriods() : Set<PolicyPeriod> {
    var policiesImPresentOn = Query.make(PolicyContactRole).compare(PolicyContactRole#ContactDenorm, Relop.Equals,this).select().toList()
    var setToReturn = new HashSet<PolicyPeriod>()
    policiesImPresentOn.each(\elt -> setToReturn.add(elt.Branch))
    return setToReturn
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some additional context about @Domenick Doran's answer, especially about denormalizing the relationship.

PolicyPeriod is the root of the PolicyPeriod domain graph. If you look at PolicyPeriod.eti, type = effdatedbranch.

Contacts (Persons or Companies) are of type=retireable and not in the domain graph (and are not effdated).  This is intentional because a Person/Contact may be added to PolicyCenter for non-policy related purposes.  For instance they may be an Account contact that gets a copy of policy documents but is not named on the policy, or perhaps a third party interested who may be named on a policy but has no legal role in the contract.  These types of contacts are intentionally left out of the policy domain graph.

Contacts that have a significant relationship to a Policy are added through the PolicyContactRole.  You can see the PolicyContactRole ties a person/contact to the PolicyPeriod and domain graph by looking at PolicyContactRole.eti which has type=effdated and effDatedBranchType=PolicyPeriod.  This is why Domenick's suggested property uses a query on PolicyContactRole which is essentially an association table between Contacts and Policy Periods (and Policies).

Attempting to create entity model relationships from outside the domain graph into the domain graph can have significant data integrity issues, especially when it comes to effdated entities, DBCCs, purging, and archiving. Therefore these types of changes to the entity model should be avoided.

For more information about the PolicyPeriod domain graph, please consult the Guidewire Documentation for PolicyCenter (may require login).  You can search for the topic "The archive domain graph" which has several sub-sections.  Here is a link for the Hakuba version (may require login): https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/pc/202306/dataarchiving/dataArchive/domain-graph/c_fy2479791.html

Answer (score -1):

If at all you want to persist the data, then here is a way:

As there is no such DB column to store the array of objects and hence Guidewire follows approach of having a reverse foreign key. Like if we have an array element in the entity A to entity B, then there should a reverse foreign key pointing back to Entity A.

And in your example, create array(of Policy) column in Person entity and create a foreign key in Policy pointing back to Person entity. By doing so, every row in policy tells to which person it is associated to. And if you want to get list of policies belonging to particular person, then you have to query Policy entity retrieving all rows in it associated with ID of that person.

Comment: Guidewire arrays do not use a reverse foreign key.  Typical RDBMSs follow the design pattern that the foreign key in a parent-child relationship is defined on the child.
From Oracle:
`A foreign key relationship involves a parent table that holds the initial column values, and a child table with column values that reference the parent column values. A foreign key constraint is defined on the child table.` 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.7-en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#:~:text=A%20foreign%20key%20relationship%20involves,defined%20on%20the%20child%20table.